# Wi-Fi adapter not showing any IPv4 address in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface

I have bought an Alfa AWUS036NH and I think I have set it up properly
but when I type `ifconfig` while running Kali Linux, there is no device showing an IPv4 address.

Output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef0:7ead  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f0:7e:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2057987  bytes 1965468395 (1.8 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 743272  bytes 114166643 (108.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1198257  bytes 1736573576 (1.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1198257  bytes 1736573576 (1.6 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-11-22-33-44-55-30-3A-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: You need to add more details to get helped. What are you trying to do? Wifi connection? Dhcp addres?  -  The way you have posted it seems that you don't even have a problem since you DO have an ip address on your `eth0` inteface.
Come back with more information about what you are trying to do and what is your problem so we can help you :)

Comment: I see this question is being used as a dupe target. Even though this question lacks sufficient detail about how the network device was placed in monitoring mode, this seems to be a common issue for Kali users. The are answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541775/22812 could go here.

Answer (score 3):

From your `ifconfig` output:

```
wlan0mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    unspec 00-11-22-33-44-55-30-3A-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Assuming that `wlan0` is your AWUS036NH, you've got it set up in monitor mode.  An interface in monitor mode is essentially an outside observer: it reports on all network packets it sees, but isn't part of any network, and so doesn't have an IP address.