# Wi-Fi Adapter not showing IP Address

Tags: kali-linux

this is the result of "ifconfig" on my kali machine's terminal.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:00:27:89:03:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24777  bytes 35808688 (34.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2835  bytes 281241 (274.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 730  bytes 59354 (57.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 730  bytes 59354 (57.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 10-0D-7F-C1-66-36-30-3A-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 14754  bytes 3884790 (3.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14607  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to run a network scanner on my wlan0mon interface and so I need the network IP. How to find the IP Address? Also what is that 32 digit hex code?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on Kali. From what I have read it is deliberately silent on the network emitting no packets by default. So even if network interfaces are set to "auto", I would make an un-educated guess that you should check if there is a DHCP client Daemon running.

Comment: If you're using a monitor interface there shouldn't be an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

A wireless interface on monitor mode won't get an IP address. Monitor mode is a special debug mode where Wi-Fi raw packets are listened to/captured/injected.

If you need an IP address while that device is in monitor mode, you have got to have another device having IP connectivity, be it another USB stick or the available ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

To get an IP address, you need to ever: Enable DHCP (automatically obtain IP address), this can only be used if there is a DHCP server on the network, or manually set one up (you need to know what you are doing).

However if you you do not need an IP address to do a network scan.

Comment: By default DHCP is set to automatic and there is a DHCP server as I am working on my college Wi-Fi, but still can't see the IP Address in 'ifconfig'. How can I do a network scan without my IP Address, can you tell more on that. Thanks

Comment: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?28126-Extra-Long-MAC-address-with-Monitor-mode says that it an extra long MAC address. That comes about when monitor mode is enabled on the NIC.

Comment: Depends on the scan: If just viewing (e.g. Wireshark) then no need for an IP address. If probing (e.g. nmap), then you will probably need one.

Comment: I want to detect devices in the network to get their IP Address and then run ARP Spoofing Attack. Also is there a way to know which IP is for which device if multiple devices are connected to the same network. Thanks

Comment: I ask the DHCP server for the IP addresses. Or use Bonjore/avahi/zeroconf (all the samethink but different names).

Comment: I am new to this. How can you implement this? Thanks

Comment: @Harshitmashru If you are wetting your feet, you must make your homework and research. This question stems from a lack of investment on researching. Saying "I am new to this" and expecting to be spoon fed is not good. Using these kind of tools involves understanding some underlying principles.